# Stability of limit cycle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> What can be said about the stability of the limit cycle for $r=1$ of the equation
>   $$\dot{r}=(r^2-1)\cdot (2 r \cos(\phi) - 1), \dot{\phi}=1?$$

This is a problem posed in Arnol'd's book on ODEs.
Does anybody have a good tool/matlab profram for visualizing solutions of this?
Thanks!

Comment: See my answer in this other [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635242/stability-of-limit-cycle-associated-with-a-homogenous-linear-quation/1636212#1636212).